# How to identify which process is drawing overlays on Windows desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I get random overlays as seen in the screenshot below - the boxes showing [191, 187] and [239, 172]. The numbers are never the same. They stay there even though all program windows are minimised and then randomly disappear after some time.

How do I identify which process is drawing them?

[image]

Comment: What do the numbers mean? Coordinate on your desktop?

Comment: I really don't know. They randomly appear on top of different windows.

Comment: Well, to determine which process is doing it, try closing those minimized programs one at a time until they disappear, then you'll know from there. If that doesn't do it, try closing processes through Task Manager until they go away. Most likely they are Mouse-Coordinates for your screen, any programs that may use the coordinates for the mouse to run? Maybe a trainer for a video game?